# Group Array of objects table 1 nesting of the keys from table 2. MySql - NodeJS (GET API)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have been working on a project where the DB structure is like:

---> Products: with product_id (Table 1)
---> images: with product_id (Multiple) (Table 2)

```
[
{
    "product_id": 1,
    "name": "Samsung galaxy S7 Edge",
    "slug": "samsung",
    "price": 300,
    "image_id": 1,
    "image": "samsung1.png",
    "url": "",
    "primary_image_id": 0,
    "video": null
},
{
    "product_id": 1,
    "name": "Samsung galaxy S7 Edge",
    "slug": "samsung",
    "price": 300,
    "image_id": 2,
    "image": "samsung2.png",
    "url": "",
    "primary_image_id": 1,
    "video": null
},
```

]

```
Expecting Result: 
{
"product_id": 1,
"name": "Samsung galaxy S7 Edge",
"slug": "samsung",
"price": 300,
"image": [
        {
            "image_id": 1,
            "image": "samsung1.png",
            "url": "",
            "primary_image_id": 0,
            "video": null,
            "product_id": 1,
        },
        {
            "image_id": 2,
            "image": "samsung2.png",
            "url": "",
            "primary_image_id": 1,
            "video": null,
            "product_id": 1,
        }
    ]
```

},

I tried this using simple inner join query on sql. Done this using model and controller but not from this method.

I am looking for a solution where all the images could be nested in the query result. **NodeJs get api call to fetch results from two different tables.**

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: In your previous project which database was used? noSQL or SQL?

Comment: In previous it was SQL but I used ORM, now I want to do this with this method. @BinaraMedawatta

Comment: all you need to do is join the two tables with the product id?

Comment: @BinaraMedawatta tried that but it gives me multiple rows with same product_id.

Comment: @BinaraMedawatta I have attached the photo of the SQL query result, you may check.

Comment: check whether I'm on track. You've got two collections called products and images, and you want to join them together and form something similar to what you have attached? or is it the expected result you need?

Comment: Yes, you are on track. I am looking for the result which is attached above as "expecting result"